# YouTube now forcing Tor users to solve captcha?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, captcha

It seems that YouTube has changed its visitor policies while its mandatory for Tor users to solve a captcha on each visit now.

Anybody experienced the same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to an [Invidious instance](https://instances.invidio.us/). Invidious is an alternative, open source front-end to YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I have never not experienced this. I find all Google products require me to solve a captcha when I am browsing over tor.